# PHP unlink fails to unlink zip-file - still returns true

Tags: php, xampp, unlink

**UPDATE:** The embarrassing reason why it "didn't work" just was based on the fact that i was looking at the wrong directory.

I need to unlink/delete all files inside a folder. To achieve this, I have modified a method I've found here on SO:

```
public function deleteDirContent($dirPath)
{
    if (!is_dir($dirPath)) 
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$dirPath must be a directory");
    }
    if (substr($dirPath, strlen($dirPath) - 1, 1) != '/') 
    {
        $dirPath .= '/';
    }
    $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
    foreach ($files as $file) 
    {
        if (is_dir($file)) 
        {
            $this->deleteDirContent($file);
        } 
        else 
        {
            print_r($file);
            if(unlink($file))
            {
                echo " - SUCCESS";
            }
            else
            {
                echo " - ERROR !";
            }
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

The method works fine for all files, except for `*.zip` files, as it seems. And what's even more strange about it: `unlink()` still returns true without deleting the file.

Maybe the problem is related to my PHP version and/or the fact that it's running on a Windows Server.

Relevant specs:

**PHP Version:** 5.3.1
**XAMPP Version:** xampp-win32-1.7.3
**OS:** Windows 2008 Server

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embarrassing reason why it "didn't work" just was based on the fact that i was looking at the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permissions with [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php):

```
// Read and write for owner, nothing for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0600);
```

Comment: 1. it's windows; 2. `unlink()` returns `true`

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad, sorry. I just recreated your function on OS X and it works fine when right permissions are set.